# Angular momentum sum of two 3/2 spin particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I have a question about the sum of angular momenta of two $3/2$ spin particles (considering no orbital angular momentum). Let's suppose that I can with a magnetic field collide two $3/2$ spin particles, but the first particle has always $m > 0$ $(m = 1/2 \ \ or \ \ m = 3/2)$, $m$ being  the projection of the spin on the $z$-axis. And the second particle has always $m < 0$ $(m = -1/2 \ \ or \ \ m = -3/2)$.

So my question is, will the final state angular momentum $\left|j, m\right>$, considering $j = 0, 1, 2, 3$ be equally probable?

Comment: Do you mean that the first particle is always in the $S_z$ eigenstate $|m = \frac12\rangle$ or the eigenstate $|m = \frac32\rangle$?  Or do you allow a superposition of the two, of the form $|\psi\rangle = \alpha|m = \frac12\rangle + \beta|m = \frac32\rangle$?  I suspect you may get different answers depending on that.

Comment: Hi @MichaelSeifert they are always in the eigenstate |m=1/2⟩ or the eigenstate |m=3/2⟩.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incoming state is of the form $|m_1, m_2\rangle$ (with $m_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{3}{2}$ and $m_2 = -\frac{1}{2}$ or $-\frac{3}{2}$).  If we subsequently measure $j$ and $m$, the probability of measuring a particular final state $|j,m\rangle$ will be the square of the Clebsch-Gordan coefficient $\langle m_1, m_2 | j, m\rangle$.  For this probability to be non-zero, of course, we must have $m = m_1 + m_2$.  Wikipedia has a table of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients, including [those for $j_1 = j_2 = \frac{3}{2}$;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#_j1_=_3/2,_j2_=_3/2)  so it's just a matter of looking up the appropriate coefficients, taking their absolute values, squaring them, and summing them.

For example, let's look at the probability for $m_1 = \frac{1}{2}$ and $m_2 = - \frac{1}{2}$ to be measured as having $j = 1$ and $m = 0$.  From the table, we see that $\langle \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} | 1, 0\rangle = -\sqrt{\frac{1}{20}}$, so the probability of measuring $j = 1$ in this case will be $\frac{1}{20}$.  It is evident from this result that the probabilities for different $j$ values cannot all be equally likely.

Comment: Yeah, i think i got it. But, can I calculate the probability of obtaining a final state with j = 1 or j  = 2 independent of the final  m? (i am looking for the probability to measure a state with j=1 for example, independent of the m).  I could just sum them clebsch coefficient for j=1 and every m, but the final probability wouldn't be one.

Comment: @MatthewD.: If you know $m_1$ and $m_2$ are, then there's only one possible choice for $m$:  $m = m_1 + m_2$.  So there's no need to sum over all possible $m$ (or alternately, the sum is trivial.)

Comment: but i dont know m1 and m2, rigth? I mean, I know they can be m1=1/2,3/2 and m2=-1/2,-3/2, so they can assume four pairs (3/2,-3/2);(3/2,-1/2),(1/2,-3/2) and (1/2,-1/2). Given these four possible pairs, what is the probability that the final state has j=1. There are 3 final states in the table which are possible, |1,-1>, |1,0> and |1,-1>.  What I do not understand, is that if I just know that  m1 will assume values m1>0 and m2<0, without knowing exactly which value the pair assumes, will the probably of the final state |1,0> be the same as |1,-1> for example?

Comment: @MatthewD.:  That was the point of my comment on your original question, which I interpreted to mean "both particles are in a definite, known eigenstate of $m_1$ and $m_2$."  If you're just told that $m_1>0$ and $m_2 < 0$, that's not enough information to answer the question;  you would need to know which superposition of the above four states you were dealing with.  Or it could be that you're dealing with a [mixed state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix), which would require a different technique to solve.  In either event, you need more information about your incoming state.

Comment: Oh okay, now I got it. Thank you for the discussion!

Comment: I corrected to “Gordan” with an “a” (not Gordon).  Paul Gordan (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Gordan)  was amongst other things, the thesis advisor of Emmy Noether.  See also the historical notes at https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Gordan/

Comment: Hi @MichaelSeifert , if I consider the superposition state of the particles as an equality superposition (sqrt(1/2) coefficients in the superposition), how could I solve it?

Comment: @MatthewD.    you would need to specify the magnetic substates in the decomposition.

Comment: @MatthewD.:  In general, given an incoming state $|psi\rangle$, the amplitude for each outgoing $|j,m\rangle$ state would be $\langle\psi|j,m\rangle$, and the overall probability of measuring a given $j$ value would be $\sum_m |\langle\psi|j,m\rangle|^2$.  Note that the components of the incoming state with the same value of $m = m_1 + m_2$ can interfere constructively or destructively with each other in this sum, so the relative phase of the $|\frac32, -\frac32\rangle$ and $|\frac12, -\frac12\rangle$ components will make difference in the final observations ...

Comment: ...  (even if they're indistinguishable when you measure $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the initial state.)  In other words, the states $\frac{1}{2} (|\frac32, -\frac32\rangle + |\frac12, -\frac12\rangle + |\frac32, -\frac12\rangle + |\frac12, -\frac32\rangle)$ and $\frac{1}{2} (|\frac32, -\frac32\rangle - |\frac12, -\frac12\rangle + |\frac32, -\frac12\rangle + |\frac12, -\frac32\rangle)$ will (probably) give different probabilities for the different $j$ values.